# Как вывести вместо числа название категории Yii2? GridView

Tags: php, yii2, gridview

Имеется **GridView**, но категории выведены в виде цифр. Как вывести названия из другой таблицы - категорий вместо этих цифр по связи Category_id-Title? Очень трудно дается Yii2.

[image: GridView]

Что мне нужно прописать в коде? Я пробовал по-разному, и [тут](http://www.elisdn.ru/blog/76/seo-service-on-yii2-admin-and-sef) брал, и [тут](http://nix-tips.ru/yii2-razbiraemsya-s-gridview.html). Но всё оканчивалось ошибками. Спасибо за помощь!
[image: Код]

Comment: Я вам советую и сейчас и впредь выкладывать тут свой код не в виде скриншота, а непосредственно в текстовом отформатированном виде. Редактор SO это позволяет. В случае если код большой, никто не захочет его пытаться воспроизводить, набирая его вручную у себя...

Comment: По релейшену `category.title` не работает?

Comment: @Onedev.Link прописал связь в моделях hasOne. Но в виде не удается вывести с помощью categories.Title

Comment: @BenjaminButton categor**ies** это не похоже на `hasOne` :) Проверьте что можете просто сделать `echo $model->category->title` во `view` рядом с `GridView` и в `columns` попробуйте запихнуть `category.title`.

Answer (score 3):

```
[
    'attribute' => 'category_id',
    'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList(
          $searchModel,
          'category_id',
          ArrayHelper::map(Category::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
          ['class' => 'form-control']
     ),
     'value' => 'category.name',
]
```

Вот такой метод ещё работает, на фильтр не обращайте внимания, я про `'value' => 'category.name'`. Не знаю красивее ли это, чем в предыдущем варианте, но я сам новенький. Работает так, подскажет может кто из бывалых в чем разница?

Comment: Простите конечно, но выборка в представлении плохо пахнет. Да и столько кода ради вывода свойства - красота довольно сомнительная.

Answer (score 2):

Требуется для начала определить связи в модели, например, у Вас есть модели для таблиц Category и Data, тогда в модели category будет такой метод:

```
public function getData()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Data::className(), ['id' => 'data_id']);
}
```

Подробнее [тут](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/db-active-record.md) расжёвано про Active Record.

Далее, мы можем непосредственно в GridView настроить собственный столбец:

```
<?php echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'id',
            'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
                return $model->data->title;
            },
            'format' => 'raw',
        ],

    ],
]);
```

Возможно, я что-то и упустил из виду или не совсем верно понял, что вы хотите добиться, но советую почитать [документацию на гитхабе](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/README.md), где всё довольно хорошо расжёвано.
Успехов в изучении.